# Default emulator on Windows

Tags: python, windows

What is the name of the Python emulator that comes by default with the Python install on a Windows machine?

Comment: CPython? What are you referring to?

Comment: Emulator?  There's an IDE called IDLE which includes a GUI interpreter.  Otherwise running python.exe will start an interpreter.  No emulator though. (In CPython, that is)

Comment: Are you sure you mean emulator? There is a default IDE that it comes with, which is called IDLE.

Answer (score 2):

There is no Python emulator. But if you mean the interpreter, then its file name is `python.exe` or `pythonw.exe` – the application has no metadata with an actual program name embedded. The project itself is known as *CPython* because it's the Python implementation written in C.